# Connecting dynamic data with input in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have gotten lost on a question in Google sheets re aligning dynamic data with static input data. At a high-level my problem is that I have dynamic data being pulled in a sheet where I also add in manual input data. Once the dynamic is changed it also means that the input data no longer corresponds to the right row.

**Issue:**

- Sheet 1: I have an external data pull (Importdata) that dynamically pulls in new data.
- Sheet 2: I use Query & Importrange to pull in parts of the data from sheet 1 (i only pull data where certain criteria are met)
- Sheet 2: In sheet 2 I manually add data in columns next to the pulled data (J,M,N & O are input). The problem is, that when new data is pulled in from Sheet 1 it is then pulled through to sheet 2 and changes the order of the rows. This means that the manual data I have inputted no longer corresponds to the right rows.

**Solution:**

I need a way to ensure that the inputted data corresponds with the right row. So if a new row is pulled in the manually inputted data will follow the row where it was initially entered and move up/down with the row.

**Sheets:**

[Link to Sheet 1 & Sheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jx4nd5KH-dEk7SJDXZ2dAsXp51btZVhKfoTPFFFl7b0/edit#gid=1630473967)

Really appreciate the help

Best
Palle

Comment: How does the import step work? If you mean to order your rows then Google Apps Script [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) is the right option, because you are manually changing data in your sheet. Can you please confirm that?

Comment: Palle, have a look at this question, which is similar to yours, to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993254/formula-to-make-dropdown-menu-choice-follow-specific-text.  Keeping dynamic (formula based) data and static (manually entered) data in sync is a common issue.  It often requires a bit of a redesign, or workfow change, to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt what I think is an answer here.

Basically, you need a unique key or identifier for each row of your dynamic data in Sheet1.  Possibly, this could be the derivative_id.  If not, you need to build a unique key, maybe derivative_id and the date, or some other combination.

Then you need an Update tab, where you would have the key, plus any other info you want to help guide in making your update.  And then you have your four manual update columns - currently J, M, N, O in Sheet2.

Finally, Sheet2 becomes all automated - filled by formula only.  Columns A:H continue to update dynamically, and all of the others are updated by formula, typically a VLOOKUP, as in column I, or a calculation, as in K and L.  And columns J, M, N, and O will now do VLOOKUPS against the Update tab.

So even when Sheet 2 rows are updated or reordered, the "manual" data in J, M,N, and O will still stay with the correct row, since it is tied to a unique key for the data in that row.

If this all makes sense to you, I can put together an example for you.