# Aligning static and dynamic data in Google Sheets with a unique id number?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Essentially I have three columns of data in Sheet2 (BD,BE,BF) that are the result of an index formula (BD3) which draws from data filtered from a much more complex Sheet1 and is formatted into the table in F2:BB6. The info in Sheet1 is updated and changed frequently so the data in that table and those columns are dynamically updated.

[Sheet2 seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y27Iv.png)

I've pulled the data from those three columns into Sheet3 (just by directly referencing each cell) and now I'm manually adding other data in adjacent rows. The issue I run into is when something is added or deleted in Sheet1, the static data in Sheet3 of course becomes misaligned.

The research I've done into this leads me to believe that I should be assigning a unique ID number  and then using vlookup to keep the data aligned. Specifically this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966258/connecting-dynamic-data-with-input-in-google-sheets) helped me understand what I need to do (I think), but it's still just a bit over my head for how it should look in practice.

- The data in those columns in Sheet2 is in the format that I need for Sheet3, so I could put a unique ID preceding those columns in BC, but that doesn't really help me since they're still updated dynamically, right?
- I don't really have the option to edit Sheet1 and put an ID number in there since it's formatted very precisely for other purposes and also contains a bunch more data not relevant to this task, and anyway I don't know if drawing from Sheet1 is the right choice either considering all the filtering this data has gone through in Sheet2 to look how I need it to.

I am really at a loss here so any guidance is so appreciated.

Comment: the [id+lookup hack as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75613711/5479575) would kinda work when you have static source data (rows addition/deletion supported) but its totally dynamic to start with in your case scenario. So I am not sure this workaround is goin' to be optimal here...